# ADT Package 23.0.0 do not allow to create new activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have downloaded new setup from https://developer.google.com which has Pre-installed ADT package 23.0.0. When I tried to create new project named as **AndroidLTest** that includes activity named as **MainActivity**. The resulting project created by eclipse doesn't include any thing in **/src** as well as in **/resource** folder and do not have any detail of activity in **ManifestFile.xml**.

I have retried to create new activity but the result is same.

Eclipse Version: 4.2.1
ADT Version: 23.0.0
SDK has version ranging from 2.2 to Andoid L.

Do I need to install something extra to create new activity?

Comment: This latest release is acknowledged to be a complete disaster as it's broken so much. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72603 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72649 and many others likely to get merged into one defect report. We will just have to wait until the developers get round to fixing it.

Comment: @NickT For the time being Is there any way out to work with this error prone thing?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have the same problem since 23.0.0 release.

The solution is to re-run the SDK Manager and update the version to 23.0.1 that just release today.

However this only update the SDK not the eclipse plugin. The Eclipse bundle with ADT plugin still break.

You need to download fresh new Eclipse from eclipse website and dowload ADT plugin by Install New Software inside Eclipse from this URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse